# What's wrong with such usage of the sed utility in backticks?

Tags: shell, sed

I'm running a mingw/msys shell on a 64-bit Windows and below is my session.

```
USER@FX8300 ~
$ echo $WD
C:\Users\USER\Desktop\msys\\bin\

USER@FX8300 ~
$ echo $WD | sed -e 's/\\bin\\//; s/\\/\//g'
C:/Users/USER/Desktop/msys/

USER@FX8300 ~
$ export W32BASE=`echo $WD | sed -e 's/\\bin\\//; s/\\/\//g'`
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

Now I wonder why the echo/sed combo fails in the backticks while it works perfectly fine when issued alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command substitution can be done by either backticks, which you're using, or $().

From bash reference:

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
>   retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’.
>   The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command
>   substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between
>   the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.
>
> Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

In your example, you are escaping the second forward slash, which breaks your command (in addition to not matching your string).

If you want to continue using backticks, your command should be:

```
 W32BASE=`echo $WD | sed 's/\\\\bin\\\\//g;s/\\\\/\\//g'`
```

When you use $(), backslashes are treated as you would normally expect and your command would be:

```
 W32BASE=$(echo $WD | sed 's/\\bin\\//g;s/\\/\//g')
```